# What does these runes say?

Tags: norse, runes

I was thinking of a tattoo with Nordic influence, I found this picture and I love it, but I need to know what it says (if it says anything), information about the symbols (like Yggdrasil or the Crows of Odin) would be very appreciated.

[image]

Comment: It says in English "not all who wander are lost". From a [J.R.R. Tokien poem in the LOTR](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/229-all-that-is-gold-does-not-glitter-not-all-those)

Answer (score 4):

As explained, the runes say "not all who wander are lost" (in English and in a very nonrunic mode) a line referring to [Aragorn](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/229-all-that-is-gold-does-not-glitter-not-all-those).

The two ravens are most likely Huginn and Muninn, Oðin's birds that would fly all over seeing what's to be seen.

The rune staff below seems to have originated in a 19th century collection of runic spells. [Description](https://guidetoiceland.is/history-culture/a-guide-to-icelandic-runes).

The interlocking triangles are the [valknutr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valknut), a widespread Germanic symbol.

The runes on either side of the tree are jera (year) and dagaz (day) and are [elder futhark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elder_Futhark). The tree could very well be Yggdrasil, the worldtree.