# What is this Norse symbol?

Tags: norse, iconography

It is possibly Icelandic but I can only find it in one place with no name or explanation. Similar to a helm of awe but with an A in the middle and the ends are alternating circles and crescents.

[image]

Comment: Hi. In what context did you see this? What makes you think that this isn't some modern imaginative variant? For example https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/6132/what-does-these-runes-say

Comment: I can notice 3 kinds of symbols (anarchy, venus or gold, and silver or the crescent moon of Islam) in an overal feel of a Ægishjálmur or Vegvísir. I'll write an answer on it when I get home. But I can say with reasonable certainty that this is not Icelandic. I think it's probably imagined by the artist like @Spencer mentioned.

Comment: @Spencer I saw a tattoo of this symbol and I was curious about it but after much searching I could only find it in one place online https://www.crushpixel.com/stock-vector/futhark-norse-island-viking-symbol-880341.html

Comment: @Fiona your link answered your question. Futhark Norse island and Viking symbol set Imaginary magic letters in hand drawing and writing symbols Inspired by ancient Iceland and ethnic Norse Viking Vector

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can notice 3 kinds of symbols (anarchy, Venus or gold, and silver or the crescent moon of Islam) in an overal feel of a [Ægishjálmur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helm_of_Awe) (Helm of Awe) or [Vegvísir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vegv%C3%ADsir).

### Anarchy

The A enclosed in a circle is the symbol for Anarchy.

*Do note that you stated in your question that you thought all symbols where Norse, I think that the creator took some artistic liberties to make the art more aesthetically appealing. h\t @DukeZhou*

> Anarchy is the state of a society being freely constituted without
> authorities or a governing body. It may also refer to a society or
> group of people that totally rejects a set hierarchy.<sub>[Wikipedia on Anarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anarchy)(It is a little more complicated than the quote text says but you get the idea).</sub>

[image] <sub>[Courtesy of Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anarchy#/media/File:Anarchy-symbol.svg)</sub>

### Venus/copper

The circle with stripes is the alchemical symbol for copper and Venus.
Copper was associated with the planet Venus by alchemists. In our modern world this symbol is a symbol to denote the female sex.

[image] <sub>[Courtesy of Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Female#/media/File:Venus_symbol.svg)</sub>

### Crescent moon

The crescent moon is a notable symbol of Islam (although there are disagreements by a growing group of modern Islamic scholars) but is actually more notable as the symbol of the [Ottoman Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flags_of_the_Ottoman_Empire) following the [conquest/fall of Constantinople in 1453](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fall_of_Constantinople). .

[image] <sub>[Courtesy of Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_calendar#/media/File:IslamSymbol1.svg)</sub>

The other crescent moon is the alchemical symbol for silver and The Moon

[image] <sub>[Courtesy of Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alchemical_symbol#/media/File:Crescent.svg)</sub>

Comment: I see no support of A for anarchy as a Norse symbol, but as the question relates to a tattoo, it's a good guess.  (However you should clarify this in your answer, which right now is could be construed as misleading...)  Note that the crescent can also be a symbol of bull's horns, but, based on the combination of symbols, moon is probably intended here.